# How to make a 2d array of tuples in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make a 2D array of 2-tuples of fixed dimension (say 10x10).

e.g

```
[[(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)],
 [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)],
 [(1,2), (1,2), (1,2)]]
```

There are also two ways that I'd like to generate this array:

1. An array like the example above where every element is the same tuple
2. An array which I populate iteratively with specific tuples (possibly starting with an empty array of fixed size and then using assignment)

How would I go about doing this? For #1 I tried using `numpy.tiles`:

```
>>> np.tile(np.array([1,2]), (3, 3))
array([[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]])
```

But I can't seem to copy it across columns, the columns are just concatenated.

i.e instead of:

```
[[[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]],
 [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]],
 [[1,2], [1,2], [1,2]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [numpy.full](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html):

```
numpy.full((3, 3, 2), (1, 2))
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

for <1> you can generate like this

```
[[(1,2)] * 3]*3
# get [[(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)], [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)], [(1, 2), (1, 2), (1, 2)]]
```

Comment: for <2> could you give a sample?

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.zeros((3,3,2))`

I guess would work (but its not tuples its lists...)